# Idiom for spending too much

Tags: idiom-requests

Is there english idiom for *when someone spends more money than they have*?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *They live beyond their means.*

Comment: He is always *strapped for cash*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **To live beyond one's means:** If someone is living beyond their means, they are spending more money than they can afford.
>
> Example: The more gifts she received, the more she craved, until he was living beyond his means.

— [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/to-live-beyond-your-means)

Answer (score 0):

Straight out word: **spendthrift**

[a person who spends improvidently or wastefully](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spendthrift)

Answer (score 0):

Spending like a drunken sailor

[TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/like+a+drunken+sailor) gives:

like a drunken sailor

> In an unrestrained, feckless, and frivolous
> manner. Usually used in reference to spending money.
> He always starts
> spending money like a drunken sailor right after he gets paid, then
> struggles to cover his rent and bills toward the end of the month.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).